# Crash on second view transition

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

```
  if (! self.mainPage)
{ self.mainPage= [[MainGameDisplay alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; }
[self presentViewController: self.mainPage animated:YES completion:NULL];

[self.view addSubview:self.mainPage.view];
self.mainPage.view.frame = CGRectMake(568, 0, 568, 320);//(N = horizontal, N = vertical)
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                 animations:^{
                     //actual frame needed with an animation.
                     self.mainPage.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 568, 320);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     //ENTER HERE ANYTHING TO RUN AFTER ANIMATION IS COMPLETED:
                     [self presentViewController: self.mainPage animated:NO completion:NULL];
                     //This will make the next page load correctly after the transition, otherwise you cannot. interact with anything.
                 }];
```

> @property (strong) MainGameDisplay *mainPage;

is declared in the .h file.
This code works perfectly but only once, If I was to transition to the mainPage view, come back and transition there again, it would crash at the end of the transition. I've played around so much to fix this but it just doesn't work.

=================
Stack Trace for MainGameDisplay viewDidLoad:

```
//First transition, A-Okay.
2012-11-11 12:27:07.547 Test_Game [584:c07] (
    0   Test_Game                              0x00002dab -[MainGameDisplay viewDidLoad] + 91
    1   UIKit                               0x000f8817 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 536
    2   UIKit                               0x000f8882 -[UIViewController view] + 33
    3   Test_Game                              0x0000240e -[ViewController StartGame:] + 334
    4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x010e3705 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    5   UIKit                               0x0001a920 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
    6   UIKit                               0x0001a8b8 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    7   UIKit                               0x000db671 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    8   UIKit                               0x000dbbcf -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 578
    9   UIKit                               0x000dad38 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 546
    10  UIKit                               0x0004a33f -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 846
    11  UIKit                               0x0004a552 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 273
    12  UIKit                               0x000283aa -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 436
    13  UIKit                               0x00019cf8 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 9874
    14  GraphicsServices                    0x01beddf9 _PurpleEventCallback + 339
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x01bedad0 PurpleEventCallback + 46
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x01c07bf5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x01c07962 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x01c38bb6 __CFRunLoopRun + 2118
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x01c37f44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x01c37e1b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x01bec7e3 GSEventRunModal + 88
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x01bec668 GSEventRun + 104
    23  UIKit                               0x0001765c UIApplicationMain + 1211
    24  Test_Game                              0x00001cfd main + 141
    25  Test_Game                              0x00001c25 start + 53
)



//Second transition, crashes now.
2012-11-11 12:27:11.223 Test_Game [584:c07] (
    0   Test_Game                            0x00002dab -[MainGameDisplay viewDidLoad] + 91
    1   UIKit                               0x000f8817 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 536
    2   UIKit                               0x000f8882 -[UIViewController view] + 33
    3   Test_Game                              0x0000240e -[ViewController StartGame:] + 334
    4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x010e3705 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    5   UIKit                               0x0001a920 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
    6   UIKit                               0x0001a8b8 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    7   UIKit                               0x000db671 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    8   UIKit                               0x000dbbcf -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 578
    9   UIKit                               0x000dad38 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 546
    10  UIKit                               0x0004a33f -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 846
    11  UIKit                               0x0004a552 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 273
    12  UIKit                               0x000283aa -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 436
    13  UIKit                               0x00019cf8 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 9874
    14  GraphicsServices                    0x01beddf9 _PurpleEventCallback + 339
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x01bedad0 PurpleEventCallback + 46
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x01c07bf5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x01c07962 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x01c38bb6 __CFRunLoopRun + 2118
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x01c37f44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x01c37e1b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x01bec7e3 GSEventRunModal + 88
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x01bec668 GSEventRun + 104
    23  UIKit                               0x0001765c UIApplicationMain + 1211
    24  Test_Game                              0x00001cfd main + 141
    25  Test_Game                              0x00001c25 start + 53
)
```

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you release you property in viewDidDisapear or something like this ?
what type of crash - BAD_ACCESS ?

Comment: I'm using ARC so the compiler should do it for me if necessary.

Comment: what code on 91 line in MainGameDisplay ? as i see problem in viewDidLoad
-[MainGameDisplay viewDidLoad] + 91

Comment: A method to do with time, this isn't the problem because it didn't work before I had this method in.